# How to make the randint function exclude numbers with repeated digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

How do I make the `randint` function not generate a specific list of numbers? I have to create a random bankcard code generator without it generating numbers with 4 repeated digits like '1111' '2222'.

```
import random

bank_codes = int(input("Hur många koder ska genereras: "))
code = 0
unwanted_codes = [0000, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999]

while code < bank_codes:
    code += 1
    a = str(random.randint(1, 10000))

    if len(a) == 3:
        print('0' + a)

    elif len(a) == 2:
        print('00' + a)

    elif len(a) == 1:
        print('000' + a)

    else:
        print(a)
```

Comment: You should have a look at the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module.

Comment: Do you want to pick the same random number multiple times? Because that is definitely going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate random numbers in the range 1 to 9998, you don't need to worry about `0000` or `9999`. Using this, a very efficient hit or miss approach is possible:

```
from random import randint
unwanted_codes = set([1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888])

def rand_code():
    while True:
        code = randint(1,9998)
        if code not in unwanted_codes:
            return str(code).zfill(4)
```

The `zfill` method pads the strings on the left with 0s.

The overwhelming majority of times, one pass through the loop will suffice. It will be quite rare that more than two passes will be required.

As a quick check, `len(set(rand_code() for _ in range(100000)))` evaluates to 9990 (with high probability -- though sometimes e.g. 9989 will also be seen), which is the number of valid codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `random.randint` to generate the length of the sequence, and `random.sample` to generate the sequence itself. `random.sample` takes a collection (sometimes referred to as a "population") from which it will randomly pick `k` distinct items, given a length `k`. If you give it a collection that has, in this case, three unique instances of each digit, then you are guaranteed to never have the same digit appear more than three times in the final sequence.

```
from random import sample, randint
from string import digits

max_len = 4
length = randint(1, max_len)

population = digits * (max_len - 1)

print("".join(sample(population, k=length)).zfill(max_len))
```

Comment: I don't think the resulting distribution would be uniform, which may be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

this Is useful for you.

```
import random
bank_codes = int(input("Hur många koder ska genereras: "))
code = 0
unwanted_codes = [0000, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999]
while code < bank_codes:
    code += 1
    a = (random.randint(1, 10000))
    if a not in unwanted_codes:
        print(a)
```